# Problem with first Windows 7 gadget getting javascript to run

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

For my first windows gadget I'm trying to make one that displays the current time and date.  The code below is what I have, but I can't figure out why the javascript is not running.  Any ideas?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
    <title>Clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { width: 130px; height: 60px; margin: 1 1 1 2; }
      body { font-family: Segoe UI, Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var background;
      var interval;
      var connection_id;
      var timeZone;
      var now;

      function load() {
        try {
          interval = 1000;
          connection_id = 0;
          timeZone = System.Time.currentTimeZone;

          update();
        }
        catch(e){}
      }

      function update() {
        try {
          now = new Date(Date.parse(System.Time.getLocalTime(timeZone)));
          curDate.innerHTML = now.format('M jS, Y');
          curTime.innerHTML = now.format('h:i:s A');
          clearTimeout(connection_id);
          connection_id = setTimeout("update()", interval);
        }
        catch(e) {}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="curDate">
    </div>
    <div id="curTime">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your trying to do with the 'System.Time' references.  Try using the JavaScript 'Date' functions.  Here is a good reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Also I am not sure if this is just a typo in what you posted but it looks like your missing a closing '}'

```
 function update() {
    try {
      now = new Date(Date.parse(System.Time.getLocalTime(timeZone)));
      curDate.innerHTML = now.format('M jS, Y');
      curTime.innerHTML = now.format('h:i:s A');
      clearTimeout(connection_id);
      connection_id = setTimeout("update()", interval);
    }
    catch(e) {}
 } // <--- Here
```

Comment: Yup, I was missing the the closing brace.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` method for your date is not a native Date method. Did you define it anywhere? You could try to display the error that is thrown, using `curTime.innerHTML = e.message` in your catch clause. Check [this link](http://archworx.wordpress.com/2006/11/05/how-to-create-a-vista-sidebar-gadget/) on creating sidebar gadgets.